# zstd-compressed data is corrupt -- system halted

Tags: boot

I am using Xubuntu 20.04 on Dell Inspiron N4050. After splash screen afore mentioned error is happening. Can anybody tell me about this error and how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: It depends on you give more details: is it system installed on clean disk ? does you use compressed filesystems ?

Comment: No, i don't use compressed filesystems.

Comment: Actually 10 days ago i installed Xubuntu on an extended partition with separate boot and swap partitions. Before this OS i was using windows 8.1. and one thing more, system was working very well suddenly it stopped responding while i was downloading.

Comment: zstd compression is used to compress the kernel. Run Ubuntu's instalation image from usb, and repair `boot` partition - using gnome-disks or fsck.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: i tried inatallation from usb and right now i am facing an other issue. I humbly request you please guide me about this new problem.

Comment: when i power on my laptop i see just black screen with some noise as system is loading but there is nothing on screen.